Could not build for ios - Flutter
Getting below error while trying to build or run flutter app for iOS from Android Studio:

Failed to build iOS app Error (Xcode): Undefined symbols:
Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
invocation)
Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching
application on iPhone 15.

I have tried below commands:
pod deintegrate
pod install
pod install --repo-update

and then below commands:
flutter clean
flutter pub get

but still above error is showing while build xcode project or trying to run the flutter project app in Simulator from Android Studio.
Other details :
Simulator - iPhone 15 (iOS 17.0)
Flutter version - 3.24.5
What might be the issue? Thanks in Advance.
EDIT:
Below is the pubspec file:
    name: project
description: A flutter boilerplate project created using MobX and Provider.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  # The following adds the shared pref as a dependency in your application
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5

  # A composable, Future-based library for making HTTP requests.
  http: ^1.2.1

  # Flogs, a powerful logging framework
  #  f_logs: ^1.2.2

  # MobX is a library for reactively managing the state of your applications. Use the power of
  # observables, actions, and reactions to supercharge your Dart and Flutter apps.
  mobx: 2.1.3
  flutter_mobx: 2.0.6+5

  # An helper to easily exposes a value using InheritedWidget without having to write one.
  provider: ^6.0.0

  # String validation and sanitization for Dart. Dart 2-compatible version of validator
  validators: ^3.0.0

  # A powerful Http client for Dart
  dio: ^4.0.0
#  device_info: ^2.0.2

  # A flexible widget for user notification. Customize your text, button, duration, animations
  # and much more. For Android devs, it is made to replace Snackbars and Toasts.
  another_flushbar: ^1.10.18

  # Material Dialog
  material_dialog: ^1.0.0-nullsafety.1

  # This package provides internationalization and localization facilities, including message
  # translation, plurals and genders, date/number formatting and parsing, and bidirectional text.
  intl: ^0.19.0

  # XXTEA is a fast and secure encryption algorithm. This is a XXTEA library for Dart.
  xxtea: ^2.1.0

  # An helper to easily exposes a value using InheritedWidget without having to write one.
  sembast: ^3.0.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.1

  keyboard_actions: "^3.3.1+1"

  # for dependency injection
  injectable: ^1.4.0
  get_it: ^7.1.3
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.0

  infinite_scroll_pagination: ^4.1.0
  dots_indicator: ^2.0.0

  list_tile_switch: ^1.0.0

  open_file_safe_plus: ^0.0.5

  firebase_messaging:
  firebase_core: ^3.8.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^17.2.1+2
  package_info_plus: any
  firebase_analytics:
  firebase_crashlytics:
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.8
  local_auth: ^2.3.0
  firebase_remote_config:
  new_version_plus:
  store_redirect: ^2.0.0
  location: ^7.0.1
  flutter_colorpicker: ^1.1.0
  html_editor_enhanced:
    path: ./html_editor_enhanced
  sms_autofill: ^2.4.1

  permission_handler: ^11.3.1
#  webview_flutter_wkwebview: ^2.9.4
  carousel_slider:
  web_socket_channel: ^2.4.0

dev_dependencies:
  test: ^1.16.8
  mockito: ^5.0.7
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the launcher icon support to your application.
  # run below mentioned commands to generate launcher icons
  # flutter packages get
  # flutter packages pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
  mobx_codegen: 2.1.1
  build_runner: ^2.4.0
  analyzer: ^5.13.0
  injectable_generator: ^1.4.0
  connectivity_plus: ^6.1.0
  #for linkedin login
  linkedin_login: ^3.0.5
  #for google login
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.2
  app_links: ^6.3.2
  #for localization ref: https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization
  easy_localization: ^3.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3 #to open default app
  android_intent_plus: ^5.2.0
  flutter_switch: ^0.3.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.0+3
  file_picker: ^8.1.4
  mailto: ^2.0.0
  flutter_inappwebview: ^6.1.5
  device_info_plus: ^11.1.1
  popover: ^0.2.6+2
  image_crop_plus: ^1.0.0
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-beta.2
  badges: ^2.0.1
  logger: ^1.1.0

dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core_platform_interface: ^5.3.0
  package_info_plus_windows: 3.0.0
  ffi: ^2.1.3
  watcher: ^1.1.0
  win32: ^5.5.4
  webview_flutter_android: ^4.1.0
  webview_flutter: ^4.10.0


flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/icons/ic_launcher.png"
  android: true
  ios: true


# For information on the generic Dart art of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/lang/
    - assets/icons/2x/
    - assets/icons/3x/
    - assets/json/
    - assets/lang/domestic_audit_trail/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: ProductSans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Product-Sans-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Product-Sans-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/Product-Sans-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
    - family: HelveticaNeue
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/helvetica_neue.ttf
    - family: HelveticaNeueMedium
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/helvetica_neue_medium.ttf
    - family: HelveticaNeueLight
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/helvetica_neue_light.ttf
    - family: HelveticaNeueItalic
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/helvetica_neue_italic.ttf
    - family: HelveticaNeueBold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/helvetica_neu_bold.ttf




  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages


Can you please confirm if you have added any new dependency in pubspec.yaml?

Yes. Added pubspec file in question. pls check.
